# SVG disappears after adding / removing class in React app

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I'm wanting to have a little expand / collapse svg rotate on click in my React app and it sometimes just disappears after the click and I have been looking in the inspector and have no idea why it isn't visible.  It's happening in multiple browsers and I have recreated it in sadbox.io.

It seems to be very intermittent (sometimes it happens on the first click, sometimes you can toggle the class on and off many times before it will disappear.  If it doesn't occur after a good amount of clicking I think it will still eventually occur or refreshing the page might do something to have it trigger sooner.)

Any ideas / help would be appreciated!

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-sound-2r7z9?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like I figured out how to fix it through trial and error and looking at how it was done in a different project.  It looks like if you apply the class to a parent element of the SVG then this problem will not occur.  I'm not sure of the explanation or technical reasons for this.